# Is it correct to use the definite article in: 'I am good at the writing'?

Tags: sentence-structure, definite-article

I was arguing with a person with their sentence “I am good at the writing”. So they said since they were talking about academic things it is correct to use *the* before “writing”. My stance was you have to include *part* after “writing” like:

For instance: You can say, *I am good at **the** writing part*. But you cannot say, *I am good at **the** writing*.

I have never seen this structure before. I used Ludwig to see if I was wrong. And I found this:

> - I am good at writing. — Huffington Post
> - I'm good at writing about what I'm doing. — The New Yorker
> - I'm good at writing fake newspaper reports. — The Guardian-Books
> - "I'm good at writing about what I'm doing." he says. — The New Yorker
> - I'm a journalist, and I'm good at writing down what happened. — The New York Times
> - "I was good at school," she writes. — The New York Times - Books
> - I like writing and I'm good at it, so medical writing seems like it might be interesting. — Science Magazine
> - They were good at writing, maybe even writing a novel, but they had problem with news. — Huffington Post

([image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdUsL.png))

So, in the end I am still confused.

Comment: Also, chatgpt said it is correct to use the before writing. But it is more common to omit the.

Comment: Your friend is wrong and so are you. It is incorrect to use _the_ here, but you _can_ say "I am good at writing/spelling/dancing" without adding any other words.

Comment: Hmm, I know it is unnecessary to use additional words with writing. However, grammatically is it totally incorrect to say good at the writing part. Also, can you give me any relevant source to prove this out?

Comment: I quote: _But you cannot say, I am good at writing. I have never seen this structure before._ No, it's not incorrect to say "I am good at the writing part". I said it was incorrect to say "I am good at the writing".

Comment: @KateBunting My apologies for not being careful. I have edited it again. I forgot to put the before writing. 

Also can you please give me a relevant link to prove that I am good at the writing is incorrect. Because the person I am dealing with is pretty stubborn.

Comment: Is [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=good+at+the+writing&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) any help? I can find only one example of _good at the writing_ without the addition of something like _craft_ or _of letters_, and that's in a novel where it is spoken by an uneducated person.

Comment: Last question, would it be correct if it were a part of a conversation?

Comment: Everything that I've said applies in both conversation and writing.

Comment: Ghost, why don't you live up to your name, and 'ghost' this stubborn person? or challenge _them_ to supply proof?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I should have done that earlier. Instead I was being called a stubborn person. Also, a teacher who happens to be a native speaker says this: **"I'm good at writing" is used when referring to your ability at this skill in general. However, we can say "I'm good at the writing" (although it less common) when referring to "writing" as a particular part of an exam. Similarly, we can say "I'm good at the listening (part/paper) but I'm not good at the reading and use of English (part/paper)."**

Answer (score 1):

**I am good at the writing.** That sentence is simply wrong.

**Writing** is a *gerund*. A gerund is the present participle form of a verb. To create a gerund you simply add -ing. (there are a few special cases, but that will give you the right answer most times.) For example: walk > walking; learn > learning.

Though it has the form of a verb, a gerund functions as a noun in a sentence:

- I love ice cream.
- I love swimming.

Here **swimming** is the object of the sentence. It's the thing I love. Grammatically it has the same syntax as **ice cream**.

[Here's a link](https://www.thesaurus.com/e/grammar/whats-a-gerund/#:%7E:text=A%20gerund%20is%20a%20form,it%20acts%20like%20a%20noun.) to an introductory article on gerunds, with lots of examples, 31 in fact. (Yes indeed, I counted them all.) Now 30 of those 31 examples used the gerund without **the**. There was precisely one example which included the, and there was a very specific and precise reason for it. Here's the sentence:

> Diana quickly grew tired of **the** constant **complaining** of the rude customers.

Why is the added here? It's because here the gerund acts as a possessive noun followed by **of**: "The complaining of the customers". That's the only place I know of that you can add **the**. So in the above example you could say, "I am good at the writing of wedding invitations." Otherwise, just the gerund. Nothing else.

Comment: There **are** contexts when it's OK. eg "How are you finding journalism?" "I'm good at the writing: it's the research that gets me".

Comment: Aha, good catch.

Comment: I should have done that earlier. Instead I was being called a stubborn person. Also, a teacher who happens to be a native speaker says this: **"I'm good at writing" is used when referring to your ability at this skill in general. However, we can say "I'm good at the writing" (although it less common) when referring to "writing" as a particular part of an exam. Similarly, we can say "I'm good at the listening (part/paper) but I'm not good at the reading and use of English (part/paper)."**

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @Ghost - your teacher who is a native speaker was right. The point is that there is some context fairly close.

Comment: In English exams for learners, you may have exams that are divided into papers such as **the reading paper**, **the writing paper** and **the listening paper** "A student may be weak at the listening but stronger/better at the writing" So, it is possible to use the definite article when the context is clear.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey A fun fact, we were actually discussing one's ability. Not the exam part.